# Nodejs nodemailer error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Running Nodemailer results in the following error, then what should I do to fix it?

> Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
>       at SMTPConnection._formatError

```js
var nodemailer=require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service:'Gmail',
    auth:{
        user:'kumaresankeerthy@gmail.com',
        password:'9943886854**'
    }
});
var mailOptions={

};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    } else{
        console.log('email sent:' +info.response);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is pass not password as it is given in documentation. Example code is at following https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp

Comment: ok but i tried using pass

Comment: i  solved this by going to the following url (while connected to google with the account I want to send mail from):

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: and enalble less secure app

Comment: return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
   
  }).catch(err=>{console.log}); 
 try to use in promise like above. Also Turn on less secure app on  your google account.

Comment: okay i tried i came

Comment: Go to this url  https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps. and turn on switch button. Then Try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- solved this by going to the following url (while connected to google with the account I want to send mail from):

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps*
**you have enable less secure app in your gmail after that it will; work**

Answer (score 2):

You are giving wrong arguments in the constructor. Its `pass` not `password`

As per [official docs](https://nodemailer.com/about/)

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
        pass: account.pass // generated ethereal password
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the transporter differently, using the actual email and password of a real Google Account.

```
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'somerealemailaddress@gmail.com', //email address to send from
        pass: 'somerealemailpassword' //the actual password for that account
    }
});
```